# C++11 static assert for equality comparable type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, equality, static-assert

How to `static_assert` a template type is EqualityComparable concept in C++11?

Comment: Note that `static_assert` on template type arguments is sometimes a suboptimal idea.  You'd often rather fail to match, which requires SFINAE, instead of fail to compile, which `static_assert` does.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use the following type trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_equality_comparable : std::false_type
{ };

template<typename T>
struct is_equality_comparable<T,
    typename std::enable_if<
        true, 
        decltype(std::declval<T&>() == std::declval<T&>(), (void)0)
        >::type
    > : std::true_type
{
};
```

Which you would test this way:

```
struct X { };
struct Y { };

bool operator == (X const&, X const&) { return true; }

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_equality_comparable<int>::value, "!"); // Does not fire
    static_assert(is_equality_comparable<X>::value, "!"); // Does not fire
    static_assert(is_equality_comparable<Y>::value, "!"); // Fires!
}
```

Here is a [*live example*](http://ideone.com/nuYfaB).

Comment: Minor correction: It won't work properly if T is not default constructible - make it `std::declval<T>()` instead of `T()`.

Comment: @jrok: Absolutely. Don't know how I could overlook that. Thank you

Comment: Strictly saying, it's not 100% EqualityComparable concept checking, because Commutativity and Transitivity reqs aren't checked. But as they cannot be checked in compile time, it's not a big deal, I guess.

Comment: Note that your check assumes `operator==` accepts rvalues - use `std::declval<T&>()` for lvalues.

Comment: I understand that it doesn't make much sense to have an equality operator accepting rvalues, but what is the point of using `std::declval<T&>()` to force this restriction in the `is_equality_comparable` struct? Wouldn't it be better to have this generic code to work, regardless of how the user implemented his `operator==`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @ChristopherC: Whichever you choose (`declval<T&>` or `declval<T>`) there will always be a "non-idiomatic" signature that the trait is not going to recognize correctly. If I picked `declval<T>`, types with an `operator ==` taking *modifiable* lvalue references would be recognized as non-equality-comparable. Granted, taking by modifiable lvalue reference makes little sense, but so does (or even less) taking by rvalue reference.

Comment: Thanks @AndyProwl and @Xeo! This helped me out going into the right direction, towards answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590890/how-to-check-at-compile-time-if-a-function-that-can-be-called-with-a-specific-se).

Comment: declval<T> return a T && anyway (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval), so there is no difference between declval<T> and declval<T&>.

Comment: The std::enable_if is superfluous. 
The specialization can be simplified to
template<typename T>
struct is_equality_comparable<
        T, decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>(), (void)0)> : std::true_type
{};