# std::is_trivially_equality_comparable_v<T>

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-traits, c++20

Related but much more arcane than [C++11 static assert for equality comparable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399346/c11-static-assert-for-equality-comparable-type) —

JF Bastien's paper [N4130 "Pad Thy Atomics!"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4130.pdf) got me thinking that if we're going to use `atomic<T>::compare_exchange_weak()` where `T` is a class or struct type, such as

```
struct Count {
    int strong_count;
    int weak_count;
};
```

then we really want to static-assert two things:

First, that `T` is actually lock-free atomic:

```
template<class T>
static constexpr bool is_lockfree_atomic_v =
    std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free;
```

And second, that `compare_exchange_weak` will do what we want. Recall (or from N4130) that `compare_exchange_weak` is defined in terms of `memcmp` and `memcpy`. So we need to check that those functions will do the right thing as far as `T` is concerned:

```
template<class T>
static constexpr bool is_cmpxchgable_v =
    std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> &&
    is_trivially_equality_comparable_v<T>;
```

`is_trivially_copyable_v` is provided by the STL. But we don't have an `is_trivially_equality_comparable_v` yet — and my understanding, sadly, is that [P0515 Consistent Comparison](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r3.pdf) does not propose to provide one. (P0515 is the feature that will allow the compiler to detect that the equality operator is literally "trivial" — that it is not user-provided and that it is explicitly defaulted under such-and-such conditions. However, it does not introduce any new concept such as "trivially comparable" into the core language.)

My best stab at a "trivially comparable" trait looks like this:

```
template<class T, class U>
static constexpr bool is_equality_comparable_with_v =
    requires(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>());

template<class T>
static constexpr bool is_equality_comparable_v =
    is_equality_comparable_with_v<T, U>;

template<class T>
static constexpr bool is_trivially_equality_comparable_v =
    is_equality_comparable_v<T> &&
    std::has_unique_object_representations_v<T>;
```

However, this definition relies on `std:: has_unique_object_representations_v`, [EDIT: <s>which has undefined behavior</s> whose value is unrelated to the behavior of `operator==`] when `T` is not a scalar type. And I strongly suspect that *in practice* `has_unique_object_representations_v` will return garbage for struct types such as my original `Count` type.

```
struct Yes { int a; int b; };
struct No { short a; int b; };
using Yes2 = std::tuple<int, int>;
struct No2 { int a; int b; bool operator==(const No2&) { return true; }};
```

- Clang/libc++ does not implement `has_unique_object_representations` yet.
- MSVC does not implement `has_unique_object_representations` yet, AFAIK.
- [GCC/libstdc++ says](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ILeOtda66VqCyfmK) that `has_unique_object_representations_v<Yes>`, and even reports correctly that `not has_unique_object_representations_v<No>`, but reports incorrectly that `not has_unique_object_representations_v<Yes2>` and that `has_unique_object_representations_v<No2>`.

---

So my questions are, (1) is there a better way to test for "trivial comparability"? and (2) is there any movement in the direction of a proposal for `is_trivially_equality_comparable` (and `is_trivially_less_than_comparable` and so on), if P0515 gets into the standard for C++20? and (3) should there be?

Comment: In what universe does `No2` not have unique object representations?

Comment: Then test for pod before testing for unique representation?

Comment: @T.C.: `No2` has many different possible bit-level object representations, but all of them compare equal. So in `No2`'s case, `a == b` does *not* imply that `memcmp(a, b, sizeof a) == 0`. PODness is unrelated as far as I can tell. And yes, `has_unique_object_representations` is well-defined for an implementation-defined set of scalar types... ah, never mind, its behavior for class types is defined in bullet point (9.2) right above where I was looking. I'll edit the question.

Comment: As to tuple, it isn’t required to propagate copy/move triviality.

Comment: MSVC has had `has_unique_object_representations` (There's a tongue twister for ya) IIRC since VS 15.3. The trait agrees with libstdc++ for your types `Yes`, `No`, `Yes2`, and `No2`.

Comment: @Casey: Just to confirm, you're saying MSVC agrees with GCC's answers, right? Not that MSVC reports the "correct" answer for `Yes2` and `No2`? (Last night I started working on my C++Now 2018 talk; I've got code and benchmarks for `is_trivially_comparable_v` in https://github.com/Quuxplusone/from-scratch/tree/master/cppnow2018 .)

Comment: Yes, msvc agrees with GCC's answers.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want `has_padding_bits`. p0528 explains why in details. In short, you're exactly right on `memcpy` and `memcmp`!

There will be an updated paper in the pre-Jacksonville meeting.

**Update mid-2018**

The standards committee decided to go in another direction with p0528, and instead make cmpxchg of types with padding bits Just Work. There won't be a `has_padding_bits` for the problem p0528 wanted to solve.

There's no good answer to your question at the moment :-)

Comment: Hi JF! This is the first time I've more-than-skimmed P0528. After reading it, I still strongly believe that talking in terms of "padding bits" is too low-level to be useful in practice. Consider that `std::string` might not have any padding bits, yet it is not "trivially comparable". Consider that `using X = std::tuple<short,int,short>` might not have any padding bits (because reordering of fields), and is even *trivially copyable* with `memcpy`; and is even *trivially equality comparable* with `memcmp`; but yet `X` is not *trivially less-than comparable* with `memcmp` (because reordering).

Comment: And yeah, I recognize that `std::string` isn't *trivially copyable* either, so it's not a very illuminating example. My point is: There exist types that are trivially equality-comparable yet not trivially copyable (such as `unique_ptr` [EDIT:ish]); and there exist types that are trivially copyable yet not trivially equality-comparable (such as `float`); and I really hope that C++ post-[P0515](http://wg21.link/p0515) can deal with this subject sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, Clang trunk supports the `__is_trivially_equality_comparable(T)` intrinsic (motivated by users within libc++ such as `std::equal` and `std::find`); see [D147175](https://reviews.llvm.org/D147175). The builtin reports `true` for types that *the compiler can identify* as trivially equality comparable, which (as usual) is a subset of the set of types that we'd call "Platonically" trivially equality comparable. For example:

```
struct A {
  int i;
  bool operator==(const A& a) const = default;
};
struct B {
  int i;
  bool operator==(const B& b) const { return i == b.i; }
};
static_assert( __is_trivially_equality_comparable(A));
static_assert(!__is_trivially_equality_comparable(B));
```

Here `B` *can*, physically, be compared with `memcmp`, but the compiler doesn't *know* that, because it can't see inside the curly braces. Analogous things happen with "trivially copyable," "trivially default-constructible," and so on.

There are several corner cases that are problematic for the builtin.

First of all, note the surprising `false` answers for enum types and empty class types.

```
enum E { RED, YELLOW };
struct S { bool operator==(const S&) const = default; };
static_assert(!__is_trivially_equality_comparable(E));
static_assert(!__is_trivially_equality_comparable(S));
```

An empty struct type isn't trivially comparable because it has padding.

The enum type `E` is trivially equality comparable *now*, but it stops being trivially comparable if someone adds a free function `bool operator==(E, E) { return false; }` (which is a better match than the built-in operator candidate). The proposed Clang implementation doesn't bother to check whether that *happened* or not, because checking is difficult; instead it considers enum types never-trivially-comparable.

<strike>In fact, the proposed Clang builtin doesn't care about non-member operators at all...</strike> UPDATE: Since June 2023 ([D151623](https://reviews.llvm.org/D151623)), it handles hidden-friend operators too.

```
struct C {
  int i;
  friend bool operator==(C, C) = default;
};
static_assert(__is_trivially_equality_comparable(C)); // OK!
```

Just as a type can be "trivially copyable" without being copyable at all, a type can be "trivially equality-comparable" without being equality-comparable at all. The compiler reports `D` as trivially equality-comparable, but `std::equality_comparable<D>` is false because `d == d` is ill-formed (ambiguous). This is perceived as a feature, not a bug.

```
struct D {
  int i;
  bool operator==(const D&) const = default;
  friend bool operator==(D, D);
};
static_assert(__is_trivially_equality_comparable(D));
static_assert(!std::equality_comparable(D));
```

A type can also be trivially equality comparable when const-qualified and non-trivially comparable otherwise:

```
struct E {
  int i;
  bool operator==(const E&) const = default;
  friend bool operator==(E&, E&) { return false; }
};
```

libstdc++ and libc++ disagree as to whether an algorithm like `std::equal` uses "const" or "non-const" comparisons when applied to a non-const range, so  their `std::equal`s give two different answers [in this Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MosYfo3os). I suspect that an evil type like `E` produces "library UB," thus both results are conforming; but I didn't look it up.